# Can the Windows Telnet client be scripted?

Tags: windows, telnet

Is it possible to use the Windows Telnet client to run a series of commands in a script?

If not are there any alternatives that can be?

Comment: Yes it is. I bet this could be easily answered @StackOverflow.com

Comment: I mean, I have seen it but don't quite remember how

Comment: I second that this question could go on StackOverflow

Comment: Actually I was thinking of trying ServerFault next :-)

Comment: This is a perfectly good place for such questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a nice solution for this over on ServerFault when I asked [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/41919/can-the-windows-telnet-client-be-scripted) over there.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest installing [**Cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.com/) and using the [**ssh** client](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) with [public key authentication](http://sial.org/howto/openssh/publickey-auth/) -- so you won't even need to **`hack`** the password in (which is a bad idea at all times).